# Would Adobe Animate get huge benefits from a high end graphics card?

Tags: graphics-cards, processor

I couldn't find any definitive answer so I'm asking here if putting more of the budget towards a high end GPU is more beneficial vs a better CPU when it comes to Adobe Aninmate? The computer would not be used for gaming and will solely be for Adobe Animate. I just don't know if that software relies more on CPU or GPU to do its thing and need some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [requirements](https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/system-requirements.html) for this software you will see the only things related to GPU are OpenGL version and DirectX version. Nothing more.

(Feel free to compare it with [Lightroom](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom-classic/system-requirements.html) or [Photoshop](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/system-requirements.html) requirements where is clearly visible you need powerful GPU for better performance)

Comment: Where do I check if a graphics card has OpenGL 3.3 or later?

Comment: @user9564371, this question will be better to be asked here: https://superuser.com/

Comment: @user9564371, you can check this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1139199/409497